# Get both the parent and child values in Firebase Database with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am using some AngularJS to retrieve values in my Firebase Database under a specified parent tree. I would like to get also the value of this parent.

My database structure:

[image]

So far, my code gets the Name and PhotoUrl of each tripID under a specified UserID. But I would like to get the TripID value as well as the Name and PhotoUrl. The problem is that the TripID value is not in the child tree. How can I retrieve it ?

My JS looks like this:

```
    var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref(`trips/${userid}/trips`).once('value') 

.then(photosSnap => {
    var photosObj = photosSnap.val();
    var tripName = Object.keys(photosObj).map(key => photosObj[key].name);
    var tripPhotoUrl = Object.keys(photosObj).map(key => photosObj[key].photourl);

   $scope.repeatData = tripName.map(function (value, index) {
      return {
        data: value,
        value: tripPhotoUrl[index]
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but if you want a list of the trip keys:

```
var tripKeys = Object.keys(photosObj);
```

But extracting the separate values into arrays and then recomposing feels overly complex to me. You can just loop over the trips once to get all the data you need:

```
var trips = photosSnap.val();
$scope.repeatData = Object.keys(trips).map((key) => {
    tripKey: key,
    tripName: trips[key].name,
    tripPhotoUrl: trips[key].photourl
});
```

Or without needing `Object.keys()`:

```
var trips = [];
photosSnap.forEach((trip) => {
  trips.push({
    tripKey: trip.key,
    tripName: trip.val().name,
    tripPhotoUrl: trip.val().photourl
  });
});
$scope.repeatData = trips;
```

The last bit unfortunately requires a temporary variable, since Firebase's `DataSnapshot` class doesn't have a `map()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your second code snippet with Object.keys(), are my values stored in tripKey, tripName and tripPhotoUrl ? Because in my code above, in the html, I set ng-repeat="data in repeatData", and I used {{data.data}} and {{data.value}} to show the output.

Comment: I used more descriptive names in my code in hopes it would be clearer. You'd use `{{data.tripKey}}` in your code to get the trip key, `{{data.tripName}}` for the trip's name, and `{{data.tripPhotoUrl}}` for the trip's photo URL.

Comment: That's what I thought, though when inserting this in my HTML code, nothing shows when I run the code.

<div class="main" ng-app="test" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

        <div id="usertripinfo" ng-repeat="data in repeatData" style="background-image: url({{data.tripPhotoUrl}}); height: 300px; width: 600px;" href="">
            
    {{data.tripName}}
    
        </div>

    </div>


Here is a jsfiddle with the code : https://jsfiddle.net/vnm1fnjh/

Comment: You will notice that I on purpose didn't include my firebase credentials, and that the userid variable which is used to access the trips in the database is missing as well. When I run it on my computer with all these info, I get the same result as on the jsfiddle

Comment: I can't get the code to run, which makes it hard to help. I've included a database URL in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/puf/vnm1fnjh/4/) and gave you write access to `/45254134`. Let me know if you can reproduce it with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually tried without the Object.keys(), as show in your third code snippet, and it worked. So I guess the issue comes from the Object.keys(). Anyway it works like this so far, so I'm gonna keep it like this. I let you know if I encounter any other issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: I opened a new thread, because I'm trying to use a href inside a div with ng-repeat, this href would have a parameter coming from data.tripKey. Maybe you can have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305604/use-href-in-an-angularjs-ng-repeat-div